# jQuery .hover() enter one element, but how to get the leave triggers on a different element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this jq which is nice and simple:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#navigation ul li').hover(function(){
    $(this).find("ul").addClass("MenuBarSubmenuVisible");
  }, function(){
   $(this).find("ul").removeClass("MenuBarSubmenuVisible");
  });
});
```

However the problem is because the `.hover` event is bound to `$('#navigation ul li')` element however I want the `mouseLeave` section of the hover function to trigger when `$('#navigation ul li ul')` is left, except it must be `$(this)` instance because there will be multiple ul li ul.

I cannot do this simply through CSS (taking a website that was developed a while ago) as it is applying classes and doing all sorts of other odd things.

Many thanks.

Comment: please add the code including HTML to jsfoddle.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I always use this code all the time when creating menu links that are augmented with some jquery effects.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery(".sf-menu a").mouseenter(function(){
      jQuery(this).stop().addClass("MenuBarSubmenuVisible");
    });
    jQuery(".sf-menu a").mouseleave(function(){
      jQuery(this).stop().removeClass("MenuBarSubmenuVisible");
          });

    });
</script>
```

The '.stop' stops "weirdness" such as animations queuing up when a user passes his/her mouse quickly over a link.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K7Y6w/11/

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would separate the mousenter and mouseleave methods / selectors:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#navigation ul').on('mouseenter','li', function() {
            $(this).find("ul").addClass("MenuBarSubmenuVisible");
    }).on('mouseout','li ul',function() {
        $(this).removeClass("MenuBarSubmenuVisible");
    });
});
```